# How to call web API 2 in Eclipse

Tags: asp.net-mvc, eclipse, asp.net-web-api

I have ASP.Net MVC 5 Web API project.
I cant use asp.net web API 2 web service in android
my web service is under mvc5, Then I have created mobile app in Eclipse Juno and i use Android sdk 21
below is my edited code

```
namespace AppServices.Models
{
    public class AdvertisingRepository
    {
        private List<Advertising> Advertising = new List<Advertising>();
        private int _nextId = 1;

        public AdvertisingRepository()
        {

        }

        public List<Advertising> GetAll()
        {
            Advertising.Clear();

            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=.;Database=AppServices;User ID=sa;Password=123;";

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblAdvertising";
            sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
            myConnection.Open();
            reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            Advertising emp = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                emp = new Advertising();
                emp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                emp.SearchString = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                emp.OstanID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(2));
                emp.AdsGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3));
                Advertising.Add(emp);
            }
            myConnection.Close();

            return Advertising;
        }

        public Advertising Get(int id)
        {
            Advertising.Clear();

            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=.;Database=AppServices;User ID=sa;Password=123;";

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblAdvertising WHERE Id=" + id + "";
            sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;
            myConnection.Open();
            reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
            Advertising emp = null;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                emp = new Advertising();
                emp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
                emp.SearchString = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                emp.OstanID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(2));
                emp.AdsGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3));
                Advertising.Add(emp);
            }
            myConnection.Close();

             return Advertising.Find(p => p.Id == id);      
        }

        public Advertising Add(Advertising item)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();

            myConnection.ConnectionString = @"Server=.;Database=AppServices;User ID=sa;Password=123;";
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblAdvertising (SearchString, OstanID, AdsGroupID) VALUES (@SearchString, @OstanID, @AdsGroupID)";
            sqlCmd.Connection = myConnection;


            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchString", item.SearchString);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OstanID", item.OstanID);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsGroupID", item.AdsGroupID);
            myConnection.Open();
            int rowInserted = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Get new record id
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP (1) Id FROM tblAdvertising ORDER BY Id DESC";
            if (sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar() != DBNull.Value)
                _nextId = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            ////////////////////

            myConnection.Close();

            // old code
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }
            item.Id = _nextId;
            Advertising.Add(item);
            return item;
        }

        public void Remove(int id)
        {
            Advertising.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == id);
        }

        public bool Update(Advertising item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
            }
            int index = Advertising.FindIndex(p => p.Id == item.Id);
            if (index == -1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            Advertising.RemoveAt(index);
            Advertising.Add(item);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ASP.Net MVC 5 Web API project. I cant use asp.net web API 2 web service in android my web service is under mvc5, Then I have created mobile app in Eclipse Juno and i use Android sdk 21 below is my edited code

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues.

It starts with what looks a little careless "SELECT * FROM tblAdvertising"

That is three sins against the rules of SQL.
First there is no table called tblAdvertising. There is one called dbo.tblAdvertising. So lacking the real name SQL assumes that you mean dbo, but that might be something else as well. This will dump your performance. Best always use fully qualified names.
The second issue is that you use * as items to select. I have been a long in SQL development and can tell from own experience how often tables are changed. The person doing so might not even be aware of your application so a simple add will cause your code to break. Always use fully qualified SQL column names as well.
The final issue with your SQL is that you use a command and yet poke in text strings, even those that are unprotected against SQL injection. What if someone adds this as string  "'',0,0; truncate table tblAdvertising; --". You might be surprised how often, certainly in the past i could log in websites simply with some variation of "'' or 1=1 --". Best avoid unprotected strings that go to MSSQL or MySQL or any SQL for that matter. Also your SQLstring needs to be compiled taking a further performance hit. There is also no protection against wrong parameters or proper feedback if the result does not exist.
Besides you really do not want to select an entire table. There should be like a top 100 or you could implement some paging.
So the solution is that you use a proper stored procedure, check the parameter input and provide limited and properly formatted output.

Also your 
INSERT INTO tblAdvertising (SearchString, OstanID, AdsGroupID) VALUES (@SearchString, @OstanID, @AdsGroupID)
can be much improved.
If you update or insert there is an output statement in SQL that is massive faster than querying the max number

create type dbo.IntTable as table(i int)
go

create proc dbo.AdvertisementInsert
@SearchString varchar
, @OstanID int
, @AdsGroupID int
, @NewID int = 0 output
as
set nocount on -- important to avoid second roundtrip over the network

declare @i as dbo.IntTable  -- use predefined table variable

-- always check quality of input first
if @SearchString is null return 50001
-- also avoid rollback transaction since that is costly. 
-- Better to ask first if this not already exist
if exists(select 42 from dbo.tblAdvertising where SearchString = @SearchString) return 50002

INSERT INTO tblAdvertising (SearchString, OstanID, AdsGroupID) 
output inserted.Id into @i  -- catch new id directly into table variable
VALUES (@SearchString, @OstanID, @AdsGroupID)

-- report the result
select @NewID = i from @i   -- convert table variable to single int 
go

So now your proc can be called just using the parameters and will tell you back either 0 .. in which case the result code will tell you why it failed, or some other number matching the new identity

Enjoy